# Need a function like read() that reads integer data into buffer and obtains same buffer value as read()

Tags: c, linux, encoding, file-io, format

How can I convert integer into value/encoded character same as the buffer obtained with read(0,buff,nbytes) when I stdin same integer? Am attempting to write something similar like read() but with integer data in place of file descriptor argument that gets read into buffer.

```
like_read(int data,void *buff,size_t nbytes);
```

It should be similar to read() in the sense that it should read into buffer same value that read(0,buff,nbytes) would from stdin into its buffer. when I provide integer address directly as buffer without first using read(0,buff,nbytes), for example

```
int Integer=25
int nbytes=2;
int rlen,wlen,wlen1;
int fd = open("ttyusb.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT,0777);
wlen = write(fd, &Integer, nbytes);
wlen1 = write(1, &Integer, nbytes);//for stdout
close(fd);
```

*Expected output*

> 25

*Actual output/file content is some encoded character*

,its not giving me the desired result as first using read() to read integer into buffer from stdin and then writing that buffer into file using write() like:

```
int Integer;
int nbytes=2;
int rlen,wlen;
int fd = open("ttyusb.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT,0777);
rlen = read(0, &Integer, nbytes);
wlen = write(fd, &Integer, nbytes);
wlen1 = write(1, &Integer, nbytes);//for stdout
close(fd);
```

*Stdin*

> 25

*Expected output*

> 25

*Actual output/file content*

> 25

when I print buffer value after read(0, buffer, nbytes), it gives some encoded value:

```
int Integer, nbytes=2;
int fd = open("ttyusb.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT,0777);
rlen = read(0, &Integer, nbytes);
wlen = write(fd, &Integer, nbytes);
wlen1 = write(1, &Integer, nbytes);
printf("\nInteger buffer value %d\n",Integer);
close(fd);
```

> stdin 0 prints "Integer buffer value 2608", stdin 1 prints "Integer buffer value 2609", stdin 2 prints "Integer buffer value 2610",.....stdin 9 prints "Integer buffer value 2617"...

what encoding is read() using to convert integer values and how can I do that conversion without read()?

Comment: @user3121023 What about double digit integers? Like 10 gives 12337, 11 gives 12593, 12 gives 12849...?

Comment: The characters '1', '0' have ASCII values 0x31 and 0x30. If you read this as a little-endian, 2 byte integer, the value will be 0x3031, which is 12337. By the way, `int` is often 4 bytes in size, and if the variable is on the stack and hasn't been initialized, the other 2 bytes of the `int` will be indeterminate.

Comment: @IanAbbott Does it not capture LF for double digit like for single digit 1 0x0A31 ('1',LF)? why is it not 0x0A3031 ('1','0',LF) for 10?

Comment: @Optic_Ray If is not 0x0A3031 because you are only reading 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but my interpretation is that you are trying to copy the bytes of an `int` into a buffer. That could be implemented something like this:

```
#include <string.h>

void like_read(int data, void *buff, size_t nbytes)
{
    size_t n;

    /* Limit number of bytes to copy from data variable. */
    n = sizeof(data);
    if (n < nbytes)
        n = nbytes;
    /* Copy bytes from data variable to the buffer. */
    memcpy(buff, &data, n);
    /* If destination buffer is larger than data variable, ... */
    if (n < nbytes) {
        /* ... set the remaining bytes in the destination to all zero. */
        memset((char *)buff + n, 0, nbytes - n);
    }
}
```

---

> what encoding is read() using to convert integer values and how can I do that conversion without read()?

`read()` just reads raw data bytes from the file descriptor, without any conversion, at least on POSIX type systems such as Unix and Linux. Some other operating systems such as Microsoft Windows allow files to be opened with special flags that do some conversion on the raw data bytes, mostly for handling text files with different encodings.

The `memcpy()` call in the `like_read` function above copies raw data bytes from one memory location to another without any conversion.

---

**EDIT**

I am still not sure what you (OP) are trying to achieve, but based on your comments below, perhaps you are after a function that "prints" the integer value as decimal ASCII characters to the buffer with a newline, but truncates to a specified number of bytes. This can nearly be done by `snprintf()` but that function always writes a terminating null byte to the buffer (if the buffer size is at least 1), so isn't quite what I think you want. Therefore, `snprintf()` can be used to print the integer value to an intermediate buffer of sufficient size and then `memcpy` the result to the specified buffer. Here is an implementation of that:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void like_read(int data, void *buff, size_t nbytes)
{
    char tempbuf[24]; /* ought to be large enough... */
    size_t n;

    /* Print data value to temporary buffer. */
    n = snprintf(tempbuf, sizeof(tempbuf), "%d\n", data);
    /* n is number of bytes that would be printed to tempbuf if room. */
    /* Limit number of bytes to copy to size of temporary buffer. */
    if (n > sizeof(tempbuf))
        n = sizeof(tempbuf);
    /* Limit number of bytes to copy to nbytes. */
    if (n > nbytes)
        n = nbytes;
    /* Copy bytes from tempbuf to the buffer. */
    memcpy(buff, tempbuf, n);
    /* If destination buffer is larger than n, ... */
    if (n < nbytes) {
        /* ... set the remaining bytes in the destination to all zero. */
        memset((char *)buff + n, 0, nbytes - n);
    }
}
```

Comment: After calling your function with data value 10, buff isn't 12337 like read's buffer would be when I call read(0, &buff, 2) and stdin 10.

Comment: @Optic_Ray Well, it depends on `sizeof(int)`, the values of `data` and `nbytes`, and whether your system stores integers in little-endian or big-endian format. It is basically doing a `memcpy` from the address of the `data` variable to the buffer. On a little-endian system (such as a PC) where `sizeof(int)` is 4, setting `data` to 10 and `nbytes` to 2 will set the first two bytes pointed to by `buff` to 10, 0. Changing `data` to 12337 will set the first two bytes of `buff` to 49, 48, which are the ASCII codes for the characters '1' and '0'. I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Optic_Ray See second version of the function in my edited answer. Perhaps that is more like what you are looking for?